# Python comparing string against several regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, switch-statement

I'm pretty experienced with Perl and Ruby but new to Python so I'm hoping someone can show me the Pythonic way to accomplish the following task.  I want to compare several lines against multiple regular expressions and retrieve the matching group.  In Ruby it would be something like this:

```
# Revised to show variance in regex and related action.
data, foo, bar = [], nil, nil
input_lines.each do |line|
  if line =~ /Foo(\d+)/
    foo = $1.to_i
  elsif line =~ /Bar=(.*)$/
    bar = $1
  elsif bar
    data.push(line.to_f)
  end
end
```

My attempts in Python are turning out pretty ugly because the matching group is returned from a call to match/search on a regular expression and Python has no assignment in conditionals or switch statements.  What's the Pythonic way to do (or think!) about this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554185/match-groups-in-python.

Comment: Yes, that question is what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paul McGuire's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554185/match-groups-in-python) of using an intermediate class `REMatcher` which performs the match, stores the match group, and returns a boolean for success/fail turned out to produce the most legible code for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, but prettier:

```
regexs = [re.compile('...'), ...]

for regex in regexes:
  m = regex.match(s)
  if m:
    print m.groups()
    break
else:
  print 'No match'
```

Comment: I tried something similar but I want to take different actions based on which regex matches, so I moved from a list to a dictionary mapping the regexs to lambdas to be called if a match is found but it makes for some confusing code...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to "bind a name on the fly" in Python, such as my old [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66061-assign-and-test/) for "assign and test"; in this case I'd probably choose another such way (assuming Python 2.6, needs some slight changes if you're working with an old version of Python), something like:

```
import re
pats_marks = (r'^A:(.*)$', 'FOO'), (r'^B:(.*)$', 'BAR')
for line in lines:
    mo, m = next(((mo, m) for p, m in pats_mark for mo in [re.match(p, line)] if mo),
                 (None, None))
    if mo: print '%s: %s' % (m, mo.group(1))
    else: print 'NO MATCH: %s' % line
```

Many minor details can be adjusted, of course (for example, I just chose `(.*)` rather than `(.*?)` as the matching group -- they're equivalent given the immediately-following `$` so I chose the shorter form;-) -- you could precompile the REs, factor things out differently than the `pats_mark` tuple (e.g., with a dict indexed by RE patterns), etc.

But the substantial ideas, I think, are to make the structure data-driven, and to bind the match object to a name on the fly with the subexpression `for mo in [re.match(p, line)]`, a "loop" over a single-item list (genexps bind names only by loop, not by assignment -- some consider using this part of genexps' specs to be "tricky", but I consider it a perfectly acceptable Python idiom, esp. since it *was* considered back in the time when listcomps, genexps' "ancestors" in a sense, were being designed).

Answer (score -1):

your regex simply takes whatever is after the 3rd character onwards.

```
for line in open("file"):
    if line.startswith("A:"):
        print "FOO #{"+line[2:]+"}"
    elif line.startswith("B:"):
        print "BAR #{"+line[2:]+"}"
    else:
        print "No match"
```

Comment: nice way, but I'd use split and comparison:

begin, rest = line.split(':', 1)
if begin == "A": etc...

Comment: This is good but I'm looking for something more general, the simple regex is just for explanatory purposes, the actual regexs would be fairly complex.