# Python print both the matching groups in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to find two fixed patterns from a log file. Here is a line in a log file looks like

> passed    dangerb.xavier64.423181.k000.drmanhattan_resources.log      Aug 23
>   04:19:37  84526   362

From this log, I want to extract `drmanhattan` and `362` which is a number just before the line ends.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
import sys
import re

with open("Xavier.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        match1 = re.search(r'((\w+_\w+)|(\d+$))',line)
        if match1:
            print match1.groups()
```

However, everytime I run this script, I always get `drmanhattan` as output and not `drmanhattan  362`.

Is it because of `|` sign?

How do I tell regex to catch `this group and that group` ?

I have already consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554185/match-groups-in-python) and [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/07/python-regex-examples/) links however, it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line = 'Passed dangerb.xavier64.423181.r000.drmanhattan_resources.log Aug 23 04:19:37 84526 362'

match1 = re.search(r'(\w+_\w+).*?(\d+$)', line)
if match1:
    print match1.groups()
    # ('drmanhattan_resources', '362')
```

If you have a `test.txt` file that contains the following lines:

> Passed dangerb.xavier64.423181.r000.drmanhattan_resources.log Aug 23
>   04:19:37 84526 362 Passed
>   dangerb.xavier64.423181.r000.drmanhattan_resources.log Aug 23 04:19:37
>   84526 363 Passed
>   dangerb.xavier64.423181.r000.drmanhattan_resources.log Aug 23 04:19:37
>   84526 361

you can do:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fil:
    for line in fil:
        match1 = re.search(r'(\w+_\w+).*?(\d+)\s*$', line)
        if match1:
            print match1.groups()
# ('drmanhattan_resources', '362')
# ('drmanhattan_resources', '363')
# ('drmanhattan_resources', '361')
```

Comment: I am reading multiple lines from a file (each has the same search pattern) and only last one fetches me the output using this solution. :(

Comment: @Recker This should also work for every line of the file, maybe you have spaces or other addtional characters. See last edit.

Comment: Got it. I used `strip()` on the line object to get rid of extra spaces and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`|` mean OR so your regex catch `(\w+_\w+)` OR `(\d+$)`

Maybe you want something like this :

```
((\w+_\w+).*?(\d+$))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `re.search` you only get the first match, if any, and with `|` you tell `re` to look for *either* this *or* that pattern. As suggested in other answers, you could replace the `|` with `.*` to match "anything in between" those two pattern. Alternatively, you could use `re.findall` to get all matches:

```
>>> line = "passed dangerb.xavier64.423181.k000.drmanhattan_resources.log Aug 23 04:19:37 84526 362"
>>> re.findall(r'\w+_\w+|\d+$', line)
['drmanhattan_resources', '362']
```